# Python open() function without variable initialization. Is close() method needed?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I trying to understand file operations in Python 2.7. Script bellow is writing contents of *input_file* into *output_file*.

```
from sys import argv
script, input_file, output_file = argv

open(output_file, 'w').write(open(input_file).read())
```

Should I call close() method on files opened in example? (and how to reference object that isn't referenced by variable?) Are opened file objects kept in memory even when not referenced by variable?

<sub>English is not my native language; please excuse errors.</sub>

Comment: Yes, you should close it. That's a good reason to keep a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to use context managers:

```
with open(inputfile, 'r') as inf:
    with open(outputfile, 'w') as outf:
        out.write(in.read())
```

`close` will then be called implicitly on leaving the `with` block even if an exception is encountered.

However, for that specific example, why not just copy the file?